# Android runtime error- dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__cxa_end_cleanup" referenced by "libcryptopp.so"

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, runtimeexception, crypto++

I have been trying to compile/link/run an Android project that uses the NDK, and has 2 stages of NDK compilation. I have been able to compile using GNU-libstdc++ without including CryptoPP, a great alternative to the OpenSSL libraries for encryption. With CryptoPP, I receive the runtime error noted in the Title.

When compiling my Android NDK project, I have no compiler errors, however during runtime, the CryptoPP library is having trouble locating the symbol **"__cxa_end_cleanup"**. I have tried manually recompiling the libcryptopp.so file using STLport as well as GNU-libstdc++, and both result in the same runtime error. I have been following the instructions per http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line). I have been properly changing APP_STL when changing compilers.

Looking online, it seems that this error is related to C++ exception handling, and thus I've tried removing the line from Android.mk **"LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions"** so that exceptions are not enabled, but again, same error during runtime.

I am also loading the libraries in the correct, reverse, order in the Java side of the JNI. System.loadLibrary("cryptopp") comes before my other custom-made library is loaded.

I have also tried including the stlport_shared.so in the armeabi/ folder and loading first, before cryptopp, and same error.

Likewise I have tried including the libsupc++.a library in the armeabi/ folder when compiling with GNU-libstdc++, as this is the C++ library that adds exception handling, and have included references to it in Android.mk **"LOCAL_CFLAGS += -lsupc++"** and **"LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libsupc++.a"**

Has anyone had similar problems using CryptoPP with Android? And if so, how did you configure your makefiles to properly link the libraries? Finally, any idea why this is not causing an error during compilation, and only during runtime? The full error is pasted below:

**E/dalvikvm(15888): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.test_app/libcryptopp.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__cxa_end_cleanup" referenced by "libcryptopp.so"...**

Comment: On the wiki, under [Execute the Program](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29#Execute_the_Program), the `ANDROID_STL_LIB` (`/opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/libstlport_shared.so`) was also pushed to the device. Have you tried including `libstlport_shared.so` in your `armeabi/` folder? Also, there's no reason to try and include a static archive (`*.a`) in the folder.

Comment: "I have also tried including the stlport_shared.so in the armeabi/ folder and loading first, before cryptopp, and same error. " 
Yes, tried that too, thanks for the suggestion all the same! I still get the same runtime error related to this missing cxa_end_cleanup symbol

Comment: How did you make out here? I found a mistake in the reference material you provided - the Crypto++ wiki, the cross-compile script, the Crytpo++ patches and the prebuilt library (sadly, I wrote them all). The mistake was Crypto++'s `GNUMakefile` did *not* include `LDLLIBS` or `LDFLAGS`, so the shared object was missing a dependency on `libstlport_shared.so`. The issues are now fixed, and the material has been updated.

Comment: ping... how are you making out?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I met the same issue while using NDK and STL, and I've solved it just now. I found that my native library would depend on STL but Dalvik VM didn't load it from system automatically even I packed it into APK file. Hence I try to load it by myself by adding the line in JAVA file:

> System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");

Where my Application.mk looks like:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard
APP_STL := stlport_shared
```

Perhaps it would help to you